# How can i use wildcard routing in Angular2/4

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing, wildcard-subdomain

I am new to angular2/4. I want to use the wildcard routing in angular. also on wildcard routing. I want to call some action/method.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

HI can you do like this

```
        {
            path: '**',
            component: NotFoundComponent
        }
```

source [angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/router)

Answer (score 0):

Even if you use wildcard-routing you'd have to point to a component to load:

```
{
    path: '**',
    component: YourComponent
}
```

Then in your component you could call your action in the `ngOnInit`.